# Is it fine to state every learned behavior has an innate component ? ie. Behavior X is largely/ mostly laerned with an innate component

Tags: human-biology, ethology, behaviour

For example human acquisition of language, can we say it is learned, but has an innate component -- because there is a particular structure of the tongue, and perhaps also a specific cognitive ability which is requisite to speaking/ learning a language.

The aforementioned requisites are ones which are reliant on genetics, thus can we say there are innate components to it, even though it is largely, based on experience, as stated in the assertion below.

"The behavior of language acquisition is based on experience, and subject to continual refinement and therefore can be classified as largely learned, however, due to the requisites it also has an innate component to it"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of a cake. Is a cake determined by its ingredients or by its preparation (mixing, baking, etc)? It's a meaningless question. The cake is determined by both.

Now think of two cakes. In principal, we can now begin to talk about the causes of their *differences*. For example, if they had identical ingredients but were prepared differently, then we could say that the differences in the resulting cakes were due to different preparation.

Humans are baked cakes. Quantitative genetics is a field which tries to estimate to which extend *differences* between organisms are due to genetic factors. Learned behaviors are consistently found to be heritable in quantitative genetics studies. For example, adult vocabulary size is substantially heritable. It is not that the words are literally transmitted to the offspring, but rather genes that influence the cognitive abilities, interests and personality of the individual. That vocabulary size is "heritable" means that a substantial portion of the differences between individuals' vocabulary sizes are due to genetic differences (although by no means only due to genetic differences).

In short, what I'm trying to get at, is that you can only talk about the relative contributions of genes and environment if you're talking about it in the context of differences between individuals. In that case, yes, learned behaviors have an innate component.

Comment: Re: vocabulary size being heritable, In the child psychiatry literature, shared environment accounts for the largest component of the variability in vocabulary size, followed by unique environment, then genetic factors. This is seen in English and Chinese.  Where do you see data that "vocabulary size is substantially heritable"?

Comment: @DanHall Nope. Shared environment accounts for nearly nothing in vocabulary size. (Once the person is entering adulthood.)

Comment: can you share your data?

Comment: @DanHall For example, vocabulary tests are well known to load fairly highly on *g*, and it's well known that *g* has little shared environmental influence. But there are also studies that directly estimate heritability in vocabulary, see for example [(van der Berg, Posthuma, Boomsma: A Longitudinal Genetic Study of Vocabulary Knowledge in Adults)](https://ctg.cncr.nl/papers/2004/Berg_TR2004_vocknow.pdf).

Comment: Are there in fact any (practically reachable) limits on vocabulary size?  Personally, I have a good vocabulary in English (including Shakespearean and a good bit of Middle English), the technical jargon of several disciplines, and a reasonable bit of several other languages, yet previously-learned vocabulary doesn't seem to disappear when I add new.  So where is the heritability?

Comment: @jamesqf Can you clarify more precisely what you want answered? Perhaps you have some misunderstanding of what heritability means. More likely, I simply don't understand what exactly you're asking.

Comment: @Eff: What I'm asking is how it's possible for vocabulary size to be inherited, when 1) So much of one's vocabulary depends on environment - learning another language or the jargon of a profession demands a large increase in vocabulary; and 2) The practical limit on the size of vocabulary seems to be the amount of time one has to learn.  Within that constrant it seems to be limitless.

Comment: @jamesqf As for your (2), you can simply control for age if you wish. Whether vocabulary is limitless, perhaps it will help to think in percentiles. For example, a person may have a vocabulary in the 85th percentile (of a particular population in question). Yes, it is possible for a person to suddenly gain a huge boost in vocabulary for whatever reason. However, when you look at population level, there will almost certainly be fairly high stability in a statistical sense. Rank order people, then test them later again. The rank orders will correlate substantially (not perfectly, obviously).

Comment: @jamesqf For your first point that so much of vocabulary being environmental. Well, that has to be tested before you know that. The main goal of the entire field of quantitative genetics is to estimate to which extend differences within a population are due to genetic differences of any sort or environmental differences of any sort. For example, the study I referenced in a previous comment estimated that >50% of variance is explained by genetic differences. This means that genetics matter, but since it is not 100%, the environment clearly matters as well.

Comment: @jamesqf How can vocabulary size be (partly) heritable? The reason is, that while external factors may have an influence on vocabulary, so does individual factors. How good is the person's memory? How much does the person read? How interested is the person in learning new things, and how easily does the individual learn? Etc. All of these things are influenced by the individual's psychology and brain. And genes are important for the creation of the brain.

Comment: @ Eff: The problem is that all of those are so strongly affected by environment and personal choice that teasing out any heritable effect seems impossible.  A heritable factor would have to affect the POTENTIAL vocabulary size, not actual (since that is so strongly a product of environment), and again, the potential size seems effectively unlimited.

Comment: @jamesqf *"A heritable factor would have to affect the POTENTIAL vocabulary size, not actual..."* No. I strongly advise you to look up what *heritability* actually means in the field quantitative genetics. What I am saying is completely mainstream science. However, here is a fact that you may find interesting. Identical twins who are separated at birth have more similar verbal abilities in adulthood than non-related adoptives who were reared together in the exact same family and went to the same school and had same teachers. Just because you think it is impossible, that doesn't mean it is.